# multiple funds deposit address for ico

Tags: contract-development

how can we generate a unique funds deposit address for each investor who registers for ico. These days it is being done by many icos to prevent hacking.

This maybe very simple but I’m a newbie and still learning and was not able to find much :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary. Assuming the coins you're offering are erc20s, just have the contract they send eth to send the tokens to msg.sender.

Comment: Thanks. I no its not necessary but how can we do it if it is a requirement? If you can share any info it would be great.